# How does one fit multiple independent and overlapping Lorentzian peaks in a set of data?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting, scipy-optimize

I need to fit several Lorentzian peaks in the same dataset, some of which are overlapping. What I need most from the function is the peak positions (centers) however I can't seem to fit all the peaks in these data.

I first tried using scipy's optimize curve fit, however I wasn't able to get the bounds to work and it would try to fit the full range of spectra. I've been using the python package lmfit with decent results, however I seem to be unable to get the fit to pick the overlapping peaks well.

you can see the raw spectra with marked peaks [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpd3V.png)
and the results of my fitting [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83oE3.png)

You can find the data I am working with
[here](https://github.com/agust2010/test_data)

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import LorentzianModel

test=np.loadtxt('filename.txt')

plt.figure()
#
lz1 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz1_')
pars=lz1.guess(y,x=x)
pars.update(lz1.make_params())
pars['lz1_center'].set(0.61, min=0.5, max=0.66)
pars['lz1_amplitude'].set(0.028)
pars['lz1_sigma'].set(0.7)

lz2 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz2_')
pars.update(lz2.make_params())
pars['lz2_center'].set(0.76, min=0.67, max=0.84)
pars['lz2_amplitude'].set(0.083)
pars['lz2_sigma'].set(0.04)

lz3 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz3_')
pars.update(lz3.make_params())
pars['lz3_center'].set(0.85,min=0.84, max=0.92)
pars['lz3_amplitude'].set(0.048)
pars['lz3_sigma'].set(0.05)

lz4 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz4_')
pars.update(lz4.make_params())
pars['lz4_center'].set(0.98, min=0.94, max=1.0)
pars['lz4_amplitude'].set(0.028)
pars['lz4_sigma'].set(0.02)

lz5 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz5_')
pars.update(lz5.make_params())
pars['lz5_center'].set(1.1, min=1.0, max=1.2)
pars['lz5_amplitude'].set(0.037)
pars['lz5_sigma'].set(0.07)

lz6 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz6_')
pars.update(lz6.make_params())
pars['lz6_center'].set(1.4, min=1.2, max=1.5)
pars['lz6_amplitude'].set(0.048)
pars['lz6_sigma'].set(0.45)

lz7 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz7_')
pars.update(lz7.make_params())
pars['lz7_center'].set(1.54,min=1.4, max=1.6)
pars['lz7_amplitude'].set(0.037)
pars['lz7_sigma'].set(0.03)

lz8 = LorentzianModel(prefix='lz8_')
pars.update(lz8.make_params())
pars['lz8_center'].set(1.7, min=1.6, max=1.8)
pars['lz8_amplitude'].set(0.04)
pars['lz8_sigma'].set(0.17)

mod = lz1 + lz2 + lz3 + lz4 + lz5 + lz6 +lz7 + lz8
init = mod.eval(pars,x=x)

out=mod.fit(y,pars,x=x)
print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.5))
plt.scatter(x,y, s=1)
plt.plot(x,init,'k:')
plt.plot(x,out.best_fit, 'r-')
```

Comment: If you subtract the fitted peaks from the data, what remains are the un-fitted peaks. You could then fit those, and finally add the two sets of fitted peaks together for a final model. That might work.

Comment: a few suggestions: a) add a background component, probably quadratic or linear, b)  try setting bounds so that the `amplitude`s are positive and `sigma`s are never greater than ~1, and c) consider fixing some of the peak positions while fitting the others, and iterating on a solution.

Comment: .... or d) fix all the positions to find amplitudes and sigmas, then set those and allow the positions to be refined.

Comment: I thought about using a background component, however I need to do this for many spectra, and the peaks would shift by an amount proportional to the rotation. Unless I am misunderstanding I do have bounds in the **pars** and no **sigma** is greater than 1... As for fixing the peaks, I am not sure what you mean.

Thanks for your comments, I really appreciate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, just adding a quadratic background and lifting the bounds on the centroids should give a decent fit.

Using your data, I modified your example a little::

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import LorentzianModel, QuadraticModel

test = np.loadtxt('spectra.txt')
xdat = test[0, :]
ydat = test[1, :]

def add_peak(prefix, center, amplitude=0.005, sigma=0.05):
    peak = LorentzianModel(prefix=prefix)
    pars = peak.make_params()
    pars[prefix + 'center'].set(center)
    pars[prefix + 'amplitude'].set(amplitude)
    pars[prefix + 'sigma'].set(sigma, min=0)
    return peak, pars

model = QuadraticModel(prefix='bkg_')
params = model.make_params(a=0, b=0, c=0)

rough_peak_positions = (0.61, 0.76, 0.85, 0.99, 1.10, 1.40, 1.54, 1.7)
for i, cen in enumerate(rough_peak_positions):
    peak, pars = add_peak('lz%d_' % (i+1), cen)
    model = model + peak
    params.update(pars)

init = model.eval(params, x=xdat)
result = model.fit(ydat, params, x=xdat)
comps = result.eval_components()

print(result.fit_report(min_correl=0.5))

plt.plot(xdat, ydat, label='data')
plt.plot(xdat, result.best_fit, label='best fit')
for name, comp in comps.items():
    plt.plot(xdat, comp, '--', label=name)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

which prints a report of

```
[[Model]]
    ((((((((Model(parabolic, prefix='bkg_') + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz1_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz2_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz3_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz4_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz5_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz6_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz7_')) + Model(lorentzian, prefix='lz8_'))
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 1101
    # data points      = 800
    # variables        = 27
    chi-square         = 7.3824e-04
    reduced chi-square = 9.5504e-07
    Akaike info crit   = -11062.6801
    Bayesian info crit = -10936.1956
[[Variables]]
    bkg_c:          0.03630504 +/- 9.4269e-04 (2.60%) (init = 0)
    bkg_b:         -0.05150031 +/- 0.00272084 (5.28%) (init = 0)
    bkg_a:          0.02285577 +/- 0.00109543 (4.79%) (init = 0)
    lz1_sigma:      0.03853490 +/- 0.00224206 (5.82%) (init = 0.05)
    lz1_center:     0.60596282 +/- 0.00101699 (0.17%) (init = 0.61)
    lz1_amplitude:  0.00121362 +/- 8.0862e-05 (6.66%) (init = 0.005)
    lz1_fwhm:       0.07706979 +/- 0.00448412 (5.82%) == '2.0000000*lz1_sigma'
    lz1_height:     0.01002487 +/- 3.1221e-04 (3.11%) == '0.3183099*lz1_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz1_sigma)'
    lz2_sigma:      0.03534226 +/- 3.5893e-04 (1.02%) (init = 0.05)
    lz2_center:     0.76784323 +/- 1.9002e-04 (0.02%) (init = 0.76)
    lz2_amplitude:  0.00738785 +/- 8.9378e-05 (1.21%) (init = 0.005)
    lz2_fwhm:       0.07068452 +/- 7.1786e-04 (1.02%) == '2.0000000*lz2_sigma'
    lz2_height:     0.06653864 +/- 3.6663e-04 (0.55%) == '0.3183099*lz2_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz2_sigma)'
    lz3_sigma:      0.03948780 +/- 0.00111507 (2.82%) (init = 0.05)
    lz3_center:     0.85427526 +/- 5.4206e-04 (0.06%) (init = 0.85)
    lz3_amplitude:  0.00317016 +/- 1.1244e-04 (3.55%) (init = 0.005)
    lz3_fwhm:       0.07897560 +/- 0.00223015 (2.82%) == '2.0000000*lz3_sigma'
    lz3_height:     0.02555459 +/- 3.9771e-04 (1.56%) == '0.3183099*lz3_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz3_sigma)'
    lz4_sigma:      0.02983045 +/- 0.00283845 (9.52%) (init = 0.05)
    lz4_center:     0.99544342 +/- 0.00142552 (0.14%) (init = 0.99)
    lz4_amplitude:  6.9114e-04 +/- 7.6016e-05 (11.00%) (init = 0.005)
    lz4_fwhm:       0.05966089 +/- 0.00567690 (9.52%) == '2.0000000*lz4_sigma'
    lz4_height:     0.00737492 +/- 3.6918e-04 (5.01%) == '0.3183099*lz4_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz4_sigma)'
    lz5_sigma:      0.06666333 +/- 0.00196152 (2.94%) (init = 0.05)
    lz5_center:     1.10162076 +/- 7.8293e-04 (0.07%) (init = 1.1)
    lz5_amplitude:  0.00522275 +/- 2.2587e-04 (4.32%) (init = 0.005)
    lz5_fwhm:       0.13332666 +/- 0.00392304 (2.94%) == '2.0000000*lz5_sigma'
    lz5_height:     0.02493807 +/- 4.7491e-04 (1.90%) == '0.3183099*lz5_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz5_sigma)'
    lz6_sigma:      0.11712113 +/- 0.00307555 (2.63%) (init = 0.05)
    lz6_center:     1.43220451 +/- 0.00102240 (0.07%) (init = 1.4)
    lz6_amplitude:  0.01215451 +/- 5.1928e-04 (4.27%) (init = 0.005)
    lz6_fwhm:       0.23424227 +/- 0.00615109 (2.63%) == '2.0000000*lz6_sigma'
    lz6_height:     0.03303334 +/- 6.2184e-04 (1.88%) == '0.3183099*lz6_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz6_sigma)'
    lz7_sigma:      0.02603963 +/- 0.00335175 (12.87%) (init = 0.05)
    lz7_center:     1.55545329 +/- 0.00152567 (0.10%) (init = 1.54)
    lz7_amplitude:  4.6978e-04 +/- 7.1036e-05 (15.12%) (init = 0.005)
    lz7_fwhm:       0.05207926 +/- 0.00670351 (12.87%) == '2.0000000*lz7_sigma'
    lz7_height:     0.00574266 +/- 3.8805e-04 (6.76%) == '0.3183099*lz7_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz7_sigma)'
    lz8_sigma:      0.11332337 +/- 0.00336106 (2.97%) (init = 0.05)
    lz8_center:     1.79132485 +/- 0.00117968 (0.07%) (init = 1.7)
    lz8_amplitude:  0.00700579 +/- 3.2606e-04 (4.65%) (init = 0.005)
    lz8_fwhm:       0.22664674 +/- 0.00672212 (2.97%) == '2.0000000*lz8_sigma'
    lz8_height:     0.01967830 +/- 4.2422e-04 (2.16%) == '0.3183099*lz8_amplitude/max(2.220446049250313e-16, lz8_sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.500)
    C(bkg_b, bkg_a)                 = -0.993
    C(bkg_c, bkg_b)                 = -0.981
    C(bkg_c, bkg_a)                 =  0.966
    C(lz6_sigma, lz6_amplitude)     =  0.963
    C(lz8_sigma, lz8_amplitude)     =  0.935
    C(lz5_sigma, lz5_amplitude)     =  0.933
    C(bkg_b, lz6_amplitude)         = -0.907
    C(lz3_sigma, lz3_amplitude)     =  0.905
    <snip>
```

and shows a plot of
[image]

That may not be perfect, but should give you a pretty good start.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think that this will solve the issue completely. I guess a background subtraction fits the peaks quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try peak-o-mat (http://qceha.net), a curve fitting software written in python. It can be scripted with a syntax simliar to that of lmfit. Nevertheless picking an initial guess with few mouse clicks is way faster than looking at the data and guessing. Have a look at Matt's fit made with peak-o-mat:

[image]

Note: in order to import your data is has to be arranged in columns, not rows.